# Reducing image dimensions to reduce complexity of CNN

Tags: conv-neural-network, image-processing

How exactly should I go about deciding by how much I should reduce the dimensions of an image? I have tons of images of blood cells, each image of dimensions 1280x900. The common MNIST data set is 28x28. But I feel like reducing my images to that small would cause for lot of the fine details associated with "blood cells" would be lost. However, having 1280x900 is far too complex and will cause too many parameters. So is there a systematic way of discerning how I should resize the images?

Comment: Try with 224X224...I think that will do fine

Comment: Here's a paper that discusses the same:  Effects of JPEG compression on classification accuracy: http://www.lsgi.polyu.edu.hk/staff/zl.li/papers_pdf/image-other/INT.%20J.%20REMOTE%20SENSING,%2024(7)%202003,%20Effects%20of%20JPEG%20compression%20on%20image%20classification.pdf. May help